# How to edit the existing excel sheet using groovy, without creating a copy of the same excel

Tags: groovy, soapui

Want To edit the existing excel sheet using groovy, without creating a copy of the same excel 
Want to  Update the Results in the same excel from which the data is fetched only the output  should be  written in different cells.

I m  new to Soap UI.

kindly find the below code

```
import java.io.*
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
// Read data from excel

def f=new File("D:\\Soap.xls");
def wk= Workbook.getWorkbook(f)
def ws=wk.getSheet("Sheet1")

def count = ws.getRows()
for (int i=1;i<count;i++) {       

      Cell c1=ws.getCell(0,i)

      A=Integer.parseInt(c1.getContents())

      Cell c2=ws.getCell(1,i)

      B=Integer.parseInt(c2.getContents())
      sum = A+B

      log.info sum 

 //---------For Writing the data-------------- 

    WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(f) 
    WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheet("Sheet1")
    log.info(sheet1.isHidden())
    Label label = new Label(3,i,"Addition")
    sheet1.addCell(label)
    log.info label
    workbook1.write()
    }
```

Comment: Have you started with any code?

Comment: Yes, Kindly find the above  code , giving me  error as org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser@1a41f7ea' with class 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser' to class 'jxl.write.WritableWorkbook' error at line: 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with reading data from excel workbook first and then doing the write related tasks after you complete reading operations like below :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import jxl.*
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException
import jxl.write.*
import jxl.write.Label

log.info("Testing Started")
def reqOperationName = "someservice"
def inputDataFileName = "D:/sample/temp6.xls"

def inputDataSheetName = "Sheet1"
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName))
Sheet  sheet1 = workbook.getSheet(inputDataSheetName)
def responsesCount = 0
String[] Responses = null

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Request")
try{
    rowcount = sheet1.getRows()
    colcount = sheet1.getColumns()
     Responses = new String[rowcount-1]
    responsesCount = rowcount-1
    for(Row in 1..rowcount-1){

    String reqTagName = sheet1.getCell(0,0).getContents()
        log.info reqTagName
        def TagCount = reqholder["count(//*:"+reqTagName+")"]
        if(TagCount!=0){
            String reqTagValue = sheet1.getCell(0,Row).getContents()
            reqholder.setNodeValue("//*:"+reqTagName, reqTagValue)
            reqholder.updateProperty()                              
        }

    //test the request
    testRunner.runTestStepByName(reqOperationName)

    reqholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(reqOperationName+"#Response")
    Responses[Row-1] = reqholder.getPrettyXml().toString()
    log.info Responses[Row-1]

    }


}
catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
    workbook.close()
}



Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName));
WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(inputDataFileName), existingWorkbook);

try
{

    WritableSheet sheetToEdit = workbookCopy.getSheet("Sheet1");
    WritableCell cell;
    for (int i =0;i<Responses.size();i++)
    {
    def resholder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(Responses[i])
    resTagValue1= resholder.getNodeValue("//*:phoneNumber")
    Label l = new Label(3, i, resTagValue1.toString());
    cell = (WritableCell) l;
    sheetToEdit.addCell(cell);
    }

}
catch (Exception e) {log.info(e)}
finally{
     workbookCopy.write();
 workbookCopy.close();
 existingWorkbook.close();

}

log.info("Testing Over")
```

Comment: Thanks sameer ,  But the above code creates the copy of the excel file. I dont want to copy the excel file and  then  append the data in it . Can you suggest how it can be done in the same excel  itselff

Comment: Code is rewriting to the same sheet. Check the code again

Comment: Please mark as answer if it worked :). Happy to help